# Grove - Mech Keycap counter

Tags: arduino-uno

I am using Grove - Mech Keycap as a counter but if I continue pressing the keycap the counter continues to run. Any idea how to program it to increase counter by one only after releasing and pressing again?

```
#define BUTTON_PIN   8

bool oldState = LOW;
long timecheck;
int i = 1;

void setup() {
  pinMode(BUTTON_PIN, INPUT_PULLUP);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{

  // Get current button state.
  bool newState = digitalRead(BUTTON_PIN);

  // Check if state changed from low to high (button press).
  if (newState == HIGH && oldState == LOW) {
    timecheck = millis();
    // Short delay to debounce button.
    delay(200);
    // Check if button is still low after debounce.
    newState = digitalRead(BUTTON_PIN);

    if (newState == HIGH) {
      Serial.println("HIGH");
      Serial.println(i);
      i = i + 1;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: use the Bounce2 library (or set oldState )

Comment: You never change `oldState`...?

Comment: how & to what shell I change the `oldState`?

Comment: when you determine that the state changed ... how else would you remember the state of the system?

Comment: Change oldstate to equal newstate when oldstate and newstate differ. That way you can know when oldstate and newstate differ....